# How sub directive and parent directive should communicate in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble understanding how MVC is being used in AngularJS.
I am writing a simple tab accordion.

Lets say I have this HTML structure:

```
<my-tabs>
     <tab title="Tab One">
         <div>content 1</div>
     </tab>
     <tab title="Tab Two">
       <div>Tab 2 content</div>
     </tab>
     <tab title="Tab Three">
        <div>Tab 3 content</div>
     </tab>
</my-tabs>
```

And here is my JS. I have main directive and sub-directive:

```
directive("myTabs", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template:
            "<ul></ul>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var arrayOfTabs = element.find("li");
        },
        controller: function () {}
    };
})
              .directive('tab', function () {
                  return {
                      require: "^myTabs",
                      restrict: "E",
                      transclude: true,
                      replace: true,
                      scope: {
                          title: "@"
                      },
                      template:
                          "<li>" +
                          "  <h1 class='title'>{{title}}</h1>" +
                          "  <div class='content' ng-transclude></div>" +
                          "</li>",
                      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                          scope.openTab = function()
                          {
                              var contentWidth = element.attr("content-width");
                              element.css('width', contentWidth);
                          }

                          scope.closeTab = function ()
                          {
                              var contentWidth = element.attr("content-width");
                              element.css('width', tabCloseWidth);
                          }

                      }
                  };
              })
```

What I really don't understand is: 
the tab directive can only open/close itself, while the myTabs directive is the one that incharge of open the selected one and close all the other. BUT - how they communicate? I don't want "tab" to fire event on each selection, telling the "myTabs" to open selected tab and close all the rest. There must be a better way than $watch or $on/$broadcast for these two directive to talk with each other? What did I miss here? When user click on tab, I want "myTabs" to take control and set which tab to open and which to close, but how he can know that? there is isolated scope for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways of communication between directives:

- events ($emit/$broadcast)
- observer pattern
- "controller method invoke" (not sure what's the correct name, see explanation below).

The thing that you'd like to use is not that easy but let me explain:

1. As 4th parameter of `link` method you can access the controller of the directive
2. Add a method to the `myTabsController` to register each tab into an array by passing the scope of the tab. (I first thought that's bad practice but I've checked the source code of angular-ui-bootstrap accordion and they're doing it too. So that should be OK.)
3. Then in the `open` method you can call the `closeOthers` method of `myTabsController` and pass the currently opened tab (=scope) it will then close other elements with a `angular.forEach` loop.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jnuf29zs/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.open = true;
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  })
  .constant('tabsConfig', {
   closeOthers: true
 })
  .directive("myTabs", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {
      },
      template: "<ul ng-transclude></ul>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        //var arrayOfTabs = element.find("li");
      },
      controller: function($scope, $attrs, tabsConfig) {
        this.tabs = [];

        this.addTab = function(tab) {
          this.tabs.push(tab);
        };

        this.closeOthers = function(openTab) {
         var closeOthers = angular.isDefined($attrs.closeOthers) ?
        $scope.$eval($attrs.closeOthers) : tabsConfig.closeOthers;
          
       if (closeOthers) {
            angular.forEach(this.tabs, function(tab) {
              if (!angular.equals(tab, openTab)) {
                //console.log(tab);
                tab.closeTab();
              }
            });
          }
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('tab', function() {
      return {
        require: "^myTabs",
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          title: "@",
          open: '='
        },
        template: '<li ng-click="toggle()">' +
          "  <h1 class='title'>{{title}}</h1>" +
          "  <div class='content' ng-transclude></div>" +
          "</li>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, myTabsCtrl, ngTransclude) {

          myTabsCtrl.addTab(scope);
          //console.log('ctrl', myTabsCtrl);
          //console.log(scope.open);
          if (!scope.open) {
            closeTab();
          }
          scope.toggle = function() {
            //scope.open = !scope.open;

            if (scope.open) {
              closeTab();
            } else {
              openTab();
              myTabsCtrl.closeOthers(scope);
            }
          };
          scope.openTab = openTab;
          scope.closeTab = closeTab;

          function openTab() {
            /*var contentWidth = element.attr("content-width");
            element.css('width', contentWidth);*/
            element.find('div').css('display', 'block');
            scope.open = true;
          }

          function closeTab() {
            /*
              var contentWidth = element.attr("content-width");
              element.css('width', tabCloseWidth);*/
            element.find('div').css('display', 'none');
            scope.open = false;
          }

        }
      };
    });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:first-child {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

li {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <my-tabs close-others="{{true}}">
    <tab title="Tab One" open="open">
      <div>content 1</div>
    </tab>
    <tab title="Tab Two">
      <div>Tab 2 content</div>
    </tab>
    <tab title="Tab Three">
      <div>Tab 3 content</div>
    </tab>
  </my-tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! you really helped me to understand how to do it the right way. It look to me silly to use watch or events when two directive are depending on each other and none can live without the other. This is a better solution. Thanks a lot again for your effort and answer.

Comment: You're welcome and the answer helped me to better understand how to use the 4th parameter of link-method. (I haven't used it before.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand scopes in angularjs - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope.

Now both directives have 'isolated' scope `scope: {}` means that they 'do not know about each other' besides the fact that 'myTabs' can pass title to 'tab' using an attribute 'title'.

This should explain all you need to know https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes